# Case statement execution steps

Tags: ada

I have the following case statement:

```
A = 1

case A is                      
    when 1          => A = 2;
                    => Run;      
    when 3 .. 15    => null;   
    when 16 | 17    => Jump;    
    when 2 | 18..35 => Swing;     
    when others     => Nothing; 
end case;
```

So the case statement will go to 1 since A is initialized to 1. A will then be equal to 2, and then the code will execute Run. Does the code exit out of the case statement at this point, or will Swing be executed because A was changed to a value of 2?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Probably depends on the language you are using. According to the tag you have chosen you are using SQL. Is that correct?

Comment: ada. i'm assuming it would work the same way if written in C as a switch statement.

Comment: Ada uses `:=` for assignment.  Also you can't put multiple `=>` on one `when` clause, as you did.  That's why he asked, because this looks like a kind of mutant language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [standard, section 5.4](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-05-04.html), only the first `when` branch would be executed:

> The execution of a `case` statement chooses one and only one alternative, since the choices are exhaustive and mutually exclusive.

Logically, this makes sense too, because `A` in the header of the `case` statement could be any expression, not necessarily a single variable. If changing a state that leads to change in `case`'s expression could lead to choosing additional branches, the code would become much harder to follow (and the language would become a nightmare to implement).

Comment: almost all languages operate as such

Comment: @ScottSosna Why "almost"? I am yet to find an exception to this rule :-)

Comment: I believe C/C++ where multipart conditions using &&/ || short-circuit, but &/| don't, allowing side-effects if you want all the methods called.  And since I don't know *every* language, I figured there's gotta be an outlier somewhere...

Comment: @ScottSosna Although C++ can execute multiple `case`s in a single `switch`, only the position of the first `case` label is being computed through the `switch` expression. The rest of the case statements that get executed are fall-through from the initial case (i.e. the code just goes down the list).

Comment: only when you don't provide a break from the case: originally started and you fall through (usually a bad practice, though not only), but only evaluates once and gets you to that label or default: